# Passing function to align-region raises an error when using 'justify' rule

Tags: align

I have `*test*` buffer with following contents:

```
 1234   23347   35466
    155555      267       31
 1444444 2444 32777
```

Now I'm trying to understand how passing a callback to `align-region` works, so I wrote this script:

```el
(let* ((group -1)
       (regexp
        "\\(\\s-*[0-9]+\\)")
       (spacing 5)
       (repeat t)
       (rule
        (list (list nil (cons 'regexp regexp)
                    (cons 'group (abs group))
                    (if (< group 0)
                        (cons 'justify t)
                      (cons 'bogus nil))
                    (if (>= spacing 0)
                        (cons 'spacing spacing)
                      (cons 'column (abs spacing)))
                    (cons 'repeat repeat)))))
  (with-current-buffer "*test*"
    (align-region (point-min) (point-max) 'entire rule nil
                  (lambda (&rest r) t))))
```

I copied that rule from definition of `align-regexp`.
When I evaluate my code I get en error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument markerp (#<marker at 53 in *test*> . #<marker (moves after insertion) at 60 in *test*>))
  marker-position((#<marker at 53 in *test*> . #<marker (moves after insertion) at 60 in *test*>))
  align-areas(((#<marker (moves after insertion) at 51 in *test*> #<marker at 53 in *test*> . #<marker (moves after insertion) at 60 in *test*>) (#<marker (moves after insertion) at 22 in *test*> #<marker at 27 in *test*> . #<marker (moves after insertion) at 33 in *test*>) (#<marker (moves after insertion) at 1 in *test*> #<marker at 2 in *test*> . #<marker (moves after insertion) at 6 in *test*>)) (5 . t) (nil (regexp . "\\(\\s-*[0-9]+\\)") (group . 1) (justify . t) (spacing . 5) (repeat . t)) (lambda (&rest r) t))
  align-region(1 72 entire ((nil (regexp . "\\(\\s-*[0-9]+\\)") (group . 1) (justify . t) (spacing . 5) (repeat . t))) nil (lambda (&rest r) t))
  (save-current-buffer (set-buffer "*test*") (align-region (point-min) (point-max) (quote entire) rule nil (function (lambda (&rest r) t))))
  (let* ((group -1) (regexp "\\(\\s-*[0-9]+\\)") (spacing 5) (repeat t) (rule (list (list nil (cons (quote regexp) regexp) (cons (quote group) (abs group)) (if (< group 0) (cons (quote justify) t) (cons (quote bogus) nil)) (if (>= spacing 0) (cons (quote spacing) spacing) (cons (quote column) (abs spacing))) (cons (quote repeat) repeat))))) (save-current-buffer (set-buffer "*test*") (align-region (point-min) (point-max) (quote entire) rule nil (function (lambda (&rest r) t)))))
  eval((let* ((group -1) (regexp "\\(\\s-*[0-9]+\\)") (spacing 5) (repeat t) (rule (list (list nil (cons (quote regexp) regexp) (cons (quote group) (abs group)) (if (< group 0) (cons (quote justify) t) (cons (quote bogus) nil)) (if (>= spacing 0) (cons (quote spacing) spacing) (cons (quote column) (abs spacing))) (cons (quote repeat) repeat))))) (save-current-buffer (set-buffer "*test*") (align-region (point-min) (point-max) (quote entire) rule nil (function (lambda (&rest r) t))))) nil)
  elisp--eval-last-sexp(t)
  eval-last-sexp(t)
  eval-print-last-sexp(nil)
  funcall-interactively(eval-print-last-sexp nil)
  call-interactively(eval-print-last-sexp nil nil)
  command-execute(eval-print-last-sexp)
```

The script evaluates cleanly if I change `group` to 1 in line 1 (so I don't use `'justify` rule).
Am I missing something obvious? I tested this on emacs-25.3 and 26-0.90 and the results are the same.